# Accessing different tables using the same model Entity framework С#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Faced with the following problem: I have two tables and one model that fits them. I think it is wrong to create a separate identical model for the second table, although it is a working method. Can you tell me how to build the logic to access either the first table or the second?

Comment: It's not "wrong" to have separate entities. If you have two separate tables you have two separate concerns. Today they are identical. Tomorrow they may not be.  What is the justification for two tables instead of just one table? Why add complexity trying to swap an entity binding to different tables which will almost certainly lead to bugs and problems down the road?

Comment: @StevePyI know what you mean. I have a user testing application and one table stores the questions for the first test, and the second table stores the questions for the second test

Comment: This question is too broad and also too opinion-based for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I understand the premise behind this, I do not think it is possible to access two tables using one model in EF Core (nor do I think it is a good idea), because the Table attribute cannot be duplicated.

However, you can get over this limitation if you implement inheritance.

```
[Table("Table1")]
public class Model1 : MyBaseModel
{
}
[Table("Table2")]
public class Model2 : MyBaseModel
{
}
public class MyBaseModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

The properties from `MyBaseModel` will then be inherited to both `Model1` and `Model2` classes. Assuming that these models have the same column named `ID` you would be able to access the two tables using two different classes (albeit, with one base model) this way.